# Property 'values' does not exist on type 'unknown'. ionic/capacitor

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, capacitor

so i have been following this tutorial https://devdactic.com/sqlite-ionic-app-with-capacitor/ but I got an error in **home.page.ts** for **this.products= res.values;** it said *Property 'values' does not exist on type 'unknown'*. not sure what does it mean and how to solve it, i am totally beginner in ionic and hope anyone can help me to explain and help me with this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show me your getProductList() function from databaseService?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an error from typescript. By default in angular `tsconfig.json` it has a configuration `noImplicityAny`. That means, you have to specify types, otherwise typescript will yell at you

**Quick Fix (not-recommendable)**

```
this.databaseService.getProductList().subscribe((res: any) => {
   this.products = res.values;
});
```

### Recommended Fix

**Service**

```
interface Product {
   ...
}

interface ProductResponse {
   values: Product[];
}

getProductList() {
   return this.http.get<ProductResponse>('https://url/to/api');
}
```

// HomePage

```
products: Product[] = [];

this.databaseService.getProductList().subscribe((res) => {
   this.products = res.values;
});
```